# There is an error in a PHP calendar

Tags: php, calendar

I have a very simple script for a PHP calendar but when i try it there is a string that i don't write. Then appear "nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn" but there isn't anything like echo "nnnnnnnnnnnnnn" so i don't know what is the error.
Please help me.

[image: ERROR?]

CODE:

```
<?php

$monthNames = Array("Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo", "Aprile", "Maggio", "Giugno", "Lulglio", 
"Agosto", "Settembre", "Ottobre", "Novembre", "Dicembre");

if (!isset($_REQUEST["month"])) $_REQUEST["month"] = date("n");
if (!isset($_REQUEST["year"])) $_REQUEST["year"] = date("Y");

$cMonth = $_REQUEST["month"];
$cYear = $_REQUEST["year"];

$prev_year = $cYear;
$next_year = $cYear;
$prev_month = $cMonth-1;
$next_month = $cMonth+1;

if ($prev_month == 0 ) {
     $prev_month = 12;
     $prev_year = $cYear - 1;
}
if ($next_month == 13 ) {
    $next_month = 1;
    $next_year = $cYear + 1;
}

?>
<html>
<table width="200">
<tr align="center">
<td bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="50%" align="left">  <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?    month=". $prev_month . "&year=" . $prev_year; ?>" style="color:#FFFFFF">Prec.    </a></td>
<td width="50%" align="right"><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?    month=". $next_month . "&year=" . $next_year; ?>" style="color:#FFFFFF">Succ.    </a>  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2"     cellspacing="2">
<tr align="center">
<td colspan="7" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong><?php echo     $monthNames[$cMonth-1].' '.$cYear; ?></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">    <strong>D</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">        <strong>L</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">    <strong>M</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">    <strong>M</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">    <strong>G</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">    <strong>V</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">    <strong>S</strong></td>
</tr>
<?php 
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
$maxday = date("t",$timestamp);
$thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
$startday = $thismonth['wday'];
for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {
    if(($i % 7) == 0 ) echo "<tr>n";
    if($i < $startday) echo "<td></td>n";
    else echo "<td align='center' valign='middle' height='20px'>". ($i -         $startday + 1) . "</td>n";
    if(($i % 7) == 6 ) echo "</tr>n";
}
?>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: Nesting tables is really painful

Comment: Regardless of the table set up, `echo "<tr>n";`, `echo "<td></td>n";`, `echo "</tr>n";` What are all those "n"s for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You see the `n`'s in:

```
for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {
    if(($i % 7) == 0 ) echo "<tr>n";
    if($i < $startday) echo "<td></td>n";
    else echo "<td align='center' valign='middle' height='20px'>". ($i - $startday + 1) . "</td>n";
    if(($i % 7) == 6 ) echo "</tr>n";
}
```

Either you remove them, or you may have meant to have it write out clean HTML using `\n`

```
if(($i % 7) == 0 ) echo "<tr>" . "\n";
```

or

```
if(($i % 7) == 0 ) echo "<tr>\n";
```

and do the same for the others, following the same method.

Concatenate them.

Comment: @paolo.basso99 Stuff happens ;-) and you're welcome.